# Why Python "append" is not behaving as expected?

Tags: python, list, append

I have this code which I'm using to transform a dictionary with a list inside it's structure into a list of dictionaries adding new columns in a flat structure for each item of the internal list. This is my code:

```
origin = {
    "a":1,
    "b":2,
    "m":[
        {"c":3},
        {"c":4}
    ]
}
    
# separating the "flat" part of the structure
flat = dict()
for o in origin.keys():
    if not isinstance(origin[o], list):
        flat[o] = origin[o]

lines = list()
# starts receiving the 'flat' value, once the new lines will receive the same flat values.
new_line = flat

# getting the "non-flat" values and creating new dictionaries using the flat structure
for i in origin["m"]:
    k = list(i.keys())[0]
    v = list(i.values())[0]
    new_line[k] = v
    print(f"NEW_LINE: {str(new_line)}")
    lines.append(new_line)

print(f"LINES:\n{str(lines)}")
```

I was expecting this:

```
NEW_LINE: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
NEW_LINE: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 4}
LINES:
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 4}]
```

But I'm getting this:

```
NEW_LINE: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
NEW_LINE: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 4}
LINES:
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 4}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 4}]
```

Why?

Comment: you need to append a `copy` of the dict: `lines.append(new_line.copy())` else they are all pointing to the same object.

Comment: Thank you so much @KrishnaChaurasia !

Answer (score 0):

You need to append a copy of the `dictionary` object as `lines.append(new_line.copy())` else they are all pointing to the same object.

Note that `copy()` does a shallow copy of the object and you'll need to use `deepcopy()` for nested objects.

Read the difference between the two in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#module-copy).

> The difference between shallow and deep copying is only relevant for
> compound objects (objects that contain other objects, like lists or
> class instances):
>
> - A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the
>   extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in
>   the original.
> - A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively,
>   inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.